# How to concate the mysql query into single query using ".=" in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my form: my has three fields search by pincode, category, and by name.

```
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pincode"     id="zipsearch"  value='<?php echo $pincode;?>'  class="buttonlengths" placeholder="Search By pincode,Area,State" required/><br/><br/>
<select name="categorypincode" ize="40" class="buttonlengths" />
<option value="">select the subject</option>
<option value="Class I-V Tuition" <?php  if($categorypincode=='Class I-V Tuition') { echo 'selected'; }?>>Class I-V Tuition</option>
<option value="Class VI-VIII Tuition" <?php  if($categorypincode=='Class VI-VIII Tuition') { echo 'selected'; }?>>Class VI-VIII Tuition</option>
   </select><br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="tutorname" value="<?php echo $tutorname; ?>" class="buttonlengths" placeholder="Search By Tutor Name"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" id="tbx2"  name="submitpincode" value="Search"/>
</form>

<?php
     $pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
     $categorypincode=$_POST['categorypincode'];
     $tutorname=$_POST['tutorname'];
     if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' &&  $tutorname!='')
    {
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid where pincode LIKE '%$pincode%' and classconducted LIKE '%$categorypincode%' and name LIKE '%$tutorname%'");
    }
    else if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' )
    {
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid where pincode LIKE '%$pincode%' and classconducted LIKE '%$categorypincode%'");
    }
    else if($pincode!='')
    {
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid where
    pincode LIKE '%$pincode%'");
    }
?>
```

**Note:**
         I want to do pagination work here before that  the output should give single query. how to concatenate into single sql query. I hope you understand my query
        how to do that rest of the thing I will handle.they search first with pincode,second with pincode and categorypincode third search by name.if you see my if else you can understand.
     Next I need to do pagination here. for this only I am breaking my head. I have five more parameter in my form .any idea how to do this and concate into single query.for sample I have given my form and data. can any one guide me how to do this? further this I want to know how to do multiple search with pagination. See total I am giving 200 record. Each page I need to show 20 record. 
I except the output like this: 
show 1 to 2o of 200 total record,
Next with second page
It should shows 21 to 40 of 200. can any one guide how to first concatenate into single query and then pagination

Comment: What have you tried? Look into MySQL's `LIMIT`. Also, please stop using `mysql_query`.

Comment: Use a string variable to hold the query then, once you have the query as you want it, pass it to a sql query function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, start with the simplest form of the query, or its default value: ...but for chrissake dont execute it!

```
$sql = "SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid where pincode LIKE '%$pincode%'";
```

Then add in the other conditions, as strings and dont execute them either.

```
if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' ){
  $sql .= " and classconducted LIKE '%$categorypincode%'");
}

if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' &&  $tutorname!=''){
  $sql .= " and name LIKE '%$tutorname%'");
}
```

**Note:** I have removed the `if...else if` nesting, they wont be needed according to the arrangemen (the 1st condition can never evaluate to false if the 2nd is true).

So the full code would be:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid where pincode LIKE '%$pincode%'";

if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' ){
  $sql .= " and classconducted LIKE '%$categorypincode%'");
}

if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' &&  $tutorname!=''){
  $sql .= " and name LIKE '%$tutorname%'");
}

$sql = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

The way you are constructing your code has some major flaws, security wise, and lets not start on debbuging. But thats none of my B/S.

**Edit:** Make use of the sql `limit` if you plan to paginate. Just pointing out.

Comment: HI Nelly, Great help for me. further I want to do this work in that pagination.Honestly saying I am new to pagination  I want to show result like show 1 to 20 of 200 total record,Next with second page
It should shows 21 to 40 of 200. is it possible? please help me out. Once again my sincere thanks to you. will pagination work for this some people said use $_GET method. I am little in experience so that I am suffering can you please do it for me.

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran If it helped you, accepting it as the right answer wouldn't hurt, I will edit the post to add the pagination then a bit later today.

Comment: sorry, first I clicked wrongly,   Nelly I  have given thats. kinldy do this pagination for me.you word is great for me

Comment: Nelly kindly do it for me. I am excepting from you

Comment: My hands are full for now i'm at the office, give me time and i'll edit the post with the full code.

Comment: ok gentleman I really really thankful to you. once again you are great .little bit client is rushing me that't why .

Comment: Please Don't forgot I have given everything in my question . You got my requirement. Just remembering u.

Comment: Nelly what happen I tried at my  end but unable to finish. Please support me

Comment: Edit your question with what you have tried, and the results, or post another question with regards to the pagination. Adding the pagination answer here would be off topic.